# Bootstrap Navigation Drop Down Menu's

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to get a menu working in Bootstrap that has the following functionality.

[image]

In the example image, the menu structure is:

Self Knowledge(parent)
 - Assetments & Quizzes(child)
   -- Quizzes & Tools(child2)
 - Workshops(child)
   -- Education(child2)
etc..

When the mouse hovers over "Self Knowledge" everything is activated.
I've got the hover part kind of working as the menu activates on mouse over but only shows the first set of child items, but not the second set.

[image]

Any direction or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

---

Update:

I've installed TB Mega Menu and it's gotten me very close.

[image]

I've searched everything but I think I'm using the wrong search strings.  Is there a way to get the menu to slide right when the primary links hovered over?  I have the mega menu in the primary block on the left.